# Is Voltron (Lion force) sentient?

Tags: robots, artificial-intelligence, voltron

I'm not 100% familiar with the 2010s series, but speaking more of the original 1980s cartoon/anime, and the early 2000s semi-spin off/continuation *Voltron Force*:

[image]

[image]

It's been heavily implied that the individual Lion robots have a certain amount of autonomy, with the Blue lion in particular seeming to have a type of "psychic link" with Princess Allura. Other implications are that the Lions can or have on different occasions:

- Reacting to pain/celebrating victories with a roar.
- Act on their own to protect their pilots or each other
- Respond to verbal commands
- Act *genuinely* like big cats

Now, considering how advanced they are, this *could* just be a well crafted, futuristic A.I., but since Voltron is also based heavily in magic, it's also been inferred that there is a "Spirit" in the beasts.

When they link up to the big robot, many of the above conditions still apply to it/him. He shows facial reactions, and seems to have a "Will" or extra power to push through in desperate situations, especially if the hearts of the Team are united in the struggle.

So I was wondering if canon material **definitively state** that this is either an advanced, sentient AI., ala "Samantha" from *Her?*

Or does the robot possess a type of actual magical "spirit", ala the *Power Rangers: Wild Force* Wild Zords, which were essentially animal spirits given robotic form on this reality?

Comment: Just to be clear about terminology: Do you want to know whether they are **sentient**, which is actually a given if they are able to feel pain - a mouse is sentient, as are all vertebrates - or whether they are **sapient**, ie. have an understanding of self and think?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Both, actually. Pain recognition and self preservation aren't really the hallmarks of sentience, as I understand it, but _Self Awareness_ is.

Comment: That's kind of the point here: Yes, sentience is often understood to mean self-awareness/self-consciousness in pop culture. But actually, that is wrong and in philosophy of mind and biology, this difference is important. Being sentient literally means "feeling or **sensing** something", whereas sapient means "thinking". That is why our species is called homo *sapiens*.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Fair point. However, as we are talking about _machines,_ here  (and ones mystically empowered, to a point, to complicate issues) the difference is even hazier, considering the crossover. To my knowledge, at least a _rudimentary_ nervous system is needed to "sense" pain, physically and emotions or "feelings" are often the result of sensory feedback reactions. Pets & pack animals have been proven to show _some type_ of emotional recognition, and even _Deception,_ implying a limited "thought" capacity. If the lions are A.I.s, they are _Already_ "Thinking machines" sans "Sentience"

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Unless things have changed, the base regard for A.I.s in the real world is still "sentience", not really "sapience". And machines have _shown_ the capacity to adapt, think, learn and solve problems without actually _feeling_ anything. Again, because "feelings" or emotions are highly bound to our physiology, it's kind of hard to make an analogy to this in programs and devices; they simply have no nervous system or hormones to generate such reactions. As such, _consciousness_ may be a better measurement, but that too can be a bit nebulous to judge in cases such as this.

Answer (score 2):

Voltron was sentient; in the episode where they are saved by the Goddess from the neutron star's gravity, the goddess speaks directly to GoLion while the pilots are unconscious. Plus if you watch *Golion*, the series *Voltron* is based on, in the 1st episode it is shown he was a being that acted on his own as if he was alive.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Could you improve your answer by identifying the episode you're talking about?